# Is There Email Client For Windows That Simultaneously Download From Multiple Accounts?

Tags: windows-xp, imap, pop3, email-client, outlook-express

I use Outlook Express in Windows XP Home as email client, but i have many accounts and it takes time to download messages from all POP3 accounts.

Is there email client that allows for simultaneous downloads from multiple email accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure [Thunderbird](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/) can download multiple accounts concurrently.

Comment: Not really. One after another.

Comment: @Boris_yo see http://superuser.com/questions/143694/can-i-make-thunderbird-load-different-email-accounts-one-after-the-other-instead